# Would this PC Build be good enough for my needs?

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards, processor, desktop, video-editing

I am completely new to building PCs and I have had friends recommending me to build one instead of buy one. I did a little research but I found it extremely difficult to understand each component. So I found a PC build that someone recommended me for a $600-$650 CAD budget. Here are the specs:

[PCPartPicker part list](http://ca.pcpartpicker.com/list/GYsLJV)

- **CPU:** Intel Core i5-6400 2.7GHz Quad-Core Processor
- **Motherboard:** ASRock H110M-DGS Micro ATX LGA1151 Motherboard
- **Memory:** Crucial Ballistix Sport 8GB (1 x 8GB) DDR4-2400 Memory
- **Storage:** Western Digital Caviar Blue 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive
- **Video Card:** Asus Radeon R7 260X 2GB DirectCU II Video Card
- **Case:** BitFenix Nova ATX Mid Tower Case  ($32.79 @ DirectCanada)
- **Power Supply:** Corsair CXM 550W 80+ Bronze Certified Semi-Modular ATX Power Supply
- **Optical Drive:** Lite-On iHAS124-14 DVD/CD Writer

The total amount $609.56 CAD.

I was trying to search the proper Stack Overflow website for PC Build Advice and was told that HardwareRecs is my best bet. If not, then are there any other sites on Stack Exchange that offer PC Build advice?

Anyways, here are my questions regarding my build.

1. Will my build be capable of editing and rendering Sony Vegas videos fast?
2. What about multi-tasking? Will I still be able to play a few Flash browser games and cheap downloadable client games effectively even with opening multiple clients/browsers?
3. Are there any bottleneck or compatibility issues with this build?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't do build reviews.

Comment: Also, you were hardly told here was your best bet when you wrote the answer that said that yourself.

Comment: Which stack exchange site is dedicated for build reviews?

Comment: There isn't one, I'm afraid .

Comment: What about SuperUser? I was told that it was the best choice for asking these questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98299/where-to-post-questions-about-building-computers

Comment: Read their help centre - I'm no expert on SU scope

Answer (score 1):

IMHO AMD is a better bet for your CPU configuration when it comes to video editing, and won't hurt you when you play low and midrange games. This build features better RAM, storage, and GPU power than that listed above, for only ~50 more, and I think it would very much be worth it.

PCPartPicker part list: http://ca.pcpartpicker.com/list/6VgBbj
Price breakdown by merchant: http://ca.pcpartpicker.com/list/6VgBbj/by_merchant/

CPU: AMD FX-8300 3.3GHz 8-Core Processor  ($165.98 @ Newegg Canada)

Motherboard: MSI 970A-G43 Plus ATX AM3+/AM3 Motherboard  ($88.99 @ Newegg Canada)

Memory: Avexir Core Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR3-2400 Memory  ($59.88 @ Canada Computers)

Storage: A-Data XPG SX900 128GB 2.5" Solid State Drive  ($39.99 @ Memory Express)

Storage: Western Digital Caviar Blue 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive  ($59.93 @ Vuugo)

Video Card: Gigabyte Radeon R7 370 2GB WINDFORCE 2X Video Card  ($159.99 @ NCIX)

Case: BitFenix Comrade ATX Mid Tower Case  ($39.88 @ Canada Computers)

Power Supply: EVGA 400W ATX Power Supply  ($32.22 @ Amazon Canada)

Total: $646.86
Prices include shipping, taxes, and discounts when available
Generated by PCPartPicker 2016-07-10 02:11 EDT-0400

The one caveat here - this is NOT a machine you'd really look to upgrade. It is optimized to deliver the most bang for buck, and has much less room to upgrade than the build you found initially. I still think it's a good choice, because it will provide better performance out of the box for longer, with lower expense over the first two to three years of the build (accounting for upgrades).

Comment: Hmm, I checked the list but it says that `Some AMD 970 chipset motherboards may need a BIOS update prior to using Vishera CPUs.` Is that going to be an issue?

Comment: It isn't anymore. Pretty much all motherboards sold now have had their BIOSes updated for Vishera, since that revision of the Bulldozer arch came out in something like 2012.